# AWS KMS Documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

Can you please help me understand the meaning of sentence from KMS documentation
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/rotate-keys.html

```
automatic key rotation has no effect on the data that the KMS key protects. 
It does not rotate the data keys that the KMS key generated 
or re-encrypt any data protected by the KMS key, 
**and it will not mitigate the effect of a compromised data key.**
```

what does

```
... it will not mitigate the effect of a compromised data key.
```

mean in this context.

I need to enable KMS Rotation in multiple repos and I want to be 100% sure

Answer (score 2):

Your CMK can create [data keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#data-keys), which you can use outside of AWS to manually encrypt and decrypt your data. The important thing about data keys is that they are **symmetric**. Which means same key is used for encryption and decryption of a secret.

If AWS rotation happens, it affects only key material stored in KMS. Any data keys generated before that, are not affected as they are for external use and are symmetric. The rotation only applies to the keys stored in KMS itself, not to data keys that you generated and used outside of AWS.

So if anyone has your data key, it can be used to decrypt your secretes, as rotation do not apply to these keys.

Comment: so if anyone has datakeys (decrypted data keys ) and kms rotation happens those datakeys are still valid.

Comment: @ETL_Devs Yes, as they are totally external to KMS and the process of rotation.

Answer (score 0):

"It does not mitigate the effect of compromised key means"
For understanding sake consider KMS Key is a logic unit of two components
1.Key attributes (Key metadata) - Key ID, Key Specification , Key Usage etc
2.Reference to Key material
(In essence a KMS key means these two things)

There are three types of KMS Keys.

1. AWS owned keys - used by AWS for internal purpose
2. AWS managed Keys - used by AWS services - only metadata can be accessed
3. AWS CMK Keys - Customer can control the key but is managed by AWS on  behalf of the customer

Data keys are generated from AWS KMS CMK Keys.

Firstly we have to understand What are data keys and how they are generated ?
Ans: As known KMS Keys do not leave the KMS modules. So the maximum file can encrypt is of the only 4KB. To encrypt more data we will be using a data key that is generated form the KMS Keys. Using envelope encryption the data key encrypts the data objects in EBS or S3 while data key is encrypted by KMS Key and stored where the data is stored unlike KMS Keys that do not leave the AWS KMS HSM Modules.

Now in case of key-rotation you are changing the key material you are not changing the Key metadata nor reference to the key material i.e .AWS will decrypt the data key  by the KMS Key that it was encrypted aka the previous version of the KMS Key. We cannot instruct a particular version of KMS Key.